# How to prevent a Tasker profile from toggling back-and-forth?

Tags: tasker

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) 4.0u1 installed. I have a "Low Light" profile which activates [ScreenFilter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor) when `%LIGHT == 0` (and I'm not in certain apps which don't react well to the filter being turned on).

In dark situations, this works quite well and prevents the S3's bright (even on minimum brightness setting) screen from hurting my eyes.

The problem I have is that in dim-light situations, the filter keeps turning on and turning off, which gets so annoying I have to pop into Tasker and shut the profile off.

How to prevent the profile from toggling back-and-forth?

Comment: Would a `WAIT` at the end of that task improve the situation? You could delay the task's ending for, say, 30s. Another idea would be to set a user variable (e.g. `%LIGHT_FILTER`) to `1` when the filter is triggered on (don't forget to delete it in the exit task), and add an `IF` with something defining when the filter is on it should not trigger back unless `%LIGHT` exceeds a given threshold (e.g. trigger only when it's at least `3`, you might need to play with that value).

Answer (score 1):

Based on Izzy's suggestion, this is what I've come up with:

Profile: Toggle Screen Filter
Primary Context: Variable Set %LIGHT
Secondary Context: Not in Netflix, Safe in Cloud, etc.
Task:

```
1. Perform Task `Distance` Priority 8 Parameter 1 %LIGHT Parameter 2 %OLDLIGHT Return Value Variable %lightchange
2. If %lightchange > %LightThreshold
3.   If %ScreenFilterOn = 1
4.     Perform Task `Screen Filter Off` Priority 8
5.   Else
6.     Perform Task `Screen Filter On` Priority 8 If %LIGHT = 0
7.   End If
8. End If
9. Variable Set %OLDLIGHT To %LIGHT
```

Task `Distance`:

```
1. Variable Set Name %rval To %par1 - %par2 Do Maths True If %par1 > %par2
2. Variable Set Name %rval To %par2 - %par1 Do Maths True If %par2 > %par1
3. Variable Set Name %rval To 0 If %par1 = %par2
4. Return Value %rval
```

Task `Screen Filter On`:

```
1. Screen Filter 48.6% Soft-keys On
2. Variable Set Name %ScreenFilterOn To 1
```

Task `Screen Filter Off`:

```
1. Screen Filter 100% Soft-keys On
2. Variable Set Name %ScreenFilterOn To 0
```

I had to fiddle with the value of %LightThreshold a bit. I started out with it set to 30, but that turned out to be so high that Screen Filter never activated. With it set to 10, things seem to be working well for now. I'll report back in a couple of days.